# Running node app digitalocean and accessing it

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, digital-ocean

Im running my node app with grunt on a DO droplet. I start the server

```
Running "connect:server" (connect) task
Waiting forever...
Started connect web server on http://localhost:3000
```

But when I navigate to my `dropletIP:3000` I cannot see the app, I get:

```
This site can’t be reached

mydropletIP refused to connect.
```

Shouldn't my app be available? I don't have nginx or anything installed.

Comment: Is the port open? You won't be able to access it outside of the local network if not.

Comment: try to start it on 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost

Comment: The port should be open and I don't think I can start it with 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar problem but the solution was simple. Change from 'localhost' to '0.0.0.0' i.e

```
.listen(8080, '0.0.0.0');
```

And then to test your api just enter your static ip of droplet with port that you have entered i.e **droplet-ip:8080**

Answer (score 0):

Check the particular port is opened or not ,using following command

**sudo ufw status**

If any Firewall enabled and any port is block means you can see that.

**netstat -an | grep "LISTEN " ( List of listening port on server)**

I need this info ,then only we can find a problem

Comment: No firewall is present, all ports should be open:
 sudo ufw status
Status: inactive

Comment: It maybe your network setting problem. check your /etc/network               (auto lo
iface lo inet loopback) It should have this default config

Comment: On same port in nginx?